# Получить адрес файла из ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

В listBox необходимо по нажатию на кнопку "Принять" записать путь к файлу в переменную.
В окне отображаются реальные файлы из папки(без расширений).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Desktop");
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.txt");

 var fileNamesWithoutExtension = files
                .Select(fi => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name));
            foreach (string fn in fileNamesWithoutExtension)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(fn.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Вот где брали имена файлов для заполнения листбокса, туда и идите (© Сбербанк)

Comment: Контролы - это не хранилище данных, а инструмент для отображения.

Comment: А как правильно тогда получить?? Хоть направление подскажите.

Comment: Как был заполнен листбокс?

Comment: Добавил код заполнения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужны два значения: имя файла без расширения (которое будет показываться в листбоксе) и полный путь (по которому можно получить доступ к файлу).

Создадим модель для этих значений:

```
class FileModel
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string NameWithoutExtension { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь создадим список этих моделей и привяжем его к листбоксу:

```
var fileModels = files
    .Select(fi => new FileModel
    {
        FullName = fi.FullName,
        NameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name)
    })
    .ToList();

listBox.DisplayMember = nameof(FileModel.NameWithoutExtension);
listBox.ValueMember = nameof(FileModel.FullName);
listBox.DataSource = fileModels;
```

В свойстве `DisplayMember` задаём то свойство, которое будет показываться пользователю.
В свойстве `ValueMember` задаём то свойство, которое потом будем получать.

Теперь можно получать путь. Например, в событии:

```
private void ListBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = (string)listBox.SelectedValue;
    // Используем filename как нам нужно.
    Text = filename;
}
```

---

Если бы у класса `FileInfo` было свойство, содержащее имя без расширения, то можно было бы использовать его, не создавая класс `FileModel`. Но так как такого свойства нет, пришлось ввести дополнительный класс. Впрочем, использование моделей в любом случае считается правильным подходом.

Comment: Большое спасибо!